# django get list of distinct 'children' of ForeignKey related model (and do this in template?)

Tags: django, django-templates, foreign-keys, django-generic-views

I'm making a database of released music albums

models.py

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(....

class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(....

class Release(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    cover_art = models.ForeignKey(Image, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

In my template (at the moment I'm using generic views) I have:

```
{% for a in album_list %}
    {% for r in a.release_set.all %}
        {% if r.cover_art %}
        # display cover art image
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is that sometimes an album has been released several times with identical cover art, in which case I'd like to display the image only once, with some text listing the releases it pertains to.

I've tried:

```
{% for i in a.release_set.cover_art %}
{% for i in a.release_set.cover_art_set %}
{% for i in a.release_set.all.cover_art %}
{% for i in a.release_set.all.cover_art_set %}
```

Or in a simpler case, I'd at least like to display the images smaller if there are more than one of them.

```
{% if a.release_set.count > 1 %} # works but displays duplicate images
{% if a.release_set.cover_art_set.count > 1 %} # doesn't work (see above)
```

Is it possible to get a list of objects related by reversing this ForeignKey lookup then asking for the set of their children? The only way I can think of is by assembling some tuples/lists in the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed this with a new method on the Album model:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(....

    def distinct_cover_images(self):
        "Returns the queryset of distinct images used for this album cover"
        pks = self.release_set.all().values_list('cover_art__pk', flat=True)
        distinct_cover_images = Images.objects.filter(pk__in=pks).distinct()
        return distinct_cover_images
```

Then the template is much more simple:

```
{% for i in a.distinct_cover_images %}
```

Credit to @danilobargen however for his contribution to this code.

Comment: Ah, of course, that somehow slipped my mind :) Good solution.

Comment: Great answer... Good idea, but I have an issue with my implementation. My `ForeginKey` relation is to a different model in another app. I thought this would still work, by just simply importing that model, but it looks like it's triggering an `ImportError` on both apps involved in the relation. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like it could be a circular import, particularly if the foreign key is defined in the other app, because that app will already be importing the model from this module. Here you could try moving the import statement `from other_app import model` to inside the function definition, i.e. on the line below `def distinct_cover_images(self)`

Answer (score 3):

If I understood this right:

- An album can have several releases
- A release has only one cover
- You want to loop over all covers of an album

In that case, the following should work:

```
{% for release in a.release_set.all %}
  {{ release.cover_art.image }}
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to prevent listing identical covers, you can either compare the covers in the loop, or prepare a set with distinct covers in your view, so you can pass it on to the template.

```
# Solution using a set
context['distinct_coverimages'] = \
    set([r.cover_art.image for r in album.release_set.all()])

# Solution using two queries, might perform better
pks = album.release_set.values_list('cover_art__pk', flat=True)
context['distinct_coverimages'] = models.Image.filter(pk__in=pks).distinct()
```

A third alternative would be creating a custom template filter for your album, to return all distinct release covers.

In any case, I recommend debugging such things in your Django shell. You can issue the shell with `./manage.py shell`. If you have installed [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions), you can also use `./manage.py shell_plus` to autoload all models. All object attributes and functions that don't require arguments (e.g. normal instance attributes or instance functions without arguments like `'string'.isalnum()`) can also be used the same way (just without the parentheses) in your template.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have been clearer: I already have a working forloop with <img src="{{ r.cover_art.image.url }}"/>. It's the removal of duplicates I'm after.

Comment: @nimasmi see my edit with the example for a possible solution.

Comment: @nimasmi I just edited my answer with another solution that prevents the usage of list comprehensions and the set.

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't know what your `context['...']` code does. I tried it in the view, within a forloop (I have to do this for `Collection.objects.all()`), and get NameError. I tried `from django.template import Context` and then `Context['...']` and got TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment. I promise I have searched, but what is this line doing?

Comment: For the record, wouldn't the first suggestion of comparing the covers in the loop fail because they're not going to be necessarily adjacent? e.g. using `{% ifchanged r.cover_art %}`. Might work if I got lucky.

Comment: @nimasmi Are you not familiar with django's contexts? See the docs on this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context The syntax above is just a way to say that you should pass on the already processed list of cover images from your view to your templates using a context object. Also, you are right about the adjacent cover images in the loop, that's why I recommend using the solution using two queries in your view :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9953/discussion-between-nimasmi-and-danilo-bargen)